# Small UPS with network access to support my NUC home server

Tags: power-supply, ups

I have a NUC at home that I want to protect with a UPS. It uses no more than 50W so the UPS does not need to be very big, but as I am often away from home I want to be able to monitor it remotely.
It should be line-interactive and include graceful shutdown and auto recovery when the power returns (should be standard anyway).

Most of the UPS with network access that I have found are huge and way oversized for me (and expensive!). Can you advise on any for this kind of low need in power?